# KeyError 'href', когда пытаюсь скачать файл с Яндекс.Диска Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, href

Вчера работал, сегодня почему-то нет. Изменений никаких не делал в код, но при этом он всё равно сломался. KeyError 'href'

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

public_key = 'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/СлучайнаяСсылка'  # Здесь моя ссылка
base_url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'

final_url = base_url + urlencode(dict(public_key=public_key))
response = requests.get(final_url)
download_url = response.json()['href'] #А здесь ошибка
```

В нём у меня всё же Response 404. Ссылка, вроде бы, правильная. Пытаюсь скачать excel-таблицу с Яндекс.Диска. Возможно, там какой-то другой base_url?

Создал свою собственную таблицу Эксель. Там такая же проблема. Возможно, что для неё требуется другой base_url

Comment: Ну значит посмотрите что там внутри `response.json()` хранится на самом деле

Comment: В самом деле пустой

Comment: Response пустой. Пытаюсь скачать excel таблицу с Яндекс.Диска. Возможно, там другой base_url или ещё что-то? Владельцом таблицы я не являюсь. Файл в публичном доступе, его можно в любой момент скачать

Comment: Проверьте правильность ссылки. Сам код рабочий, если я в него подставляю мою ссылку, то всё работает. Значит, проблема именно в public_key.

Comment: Вообще, странно, что response у вас пустой. Потому что даже если вы ошиблись в ссылке, то в response должно лежать что-то вроде такого `{'message': 'Ресурс не найден.', 'description': 'Not Found', 'error': 'NotFoundError'}`

Comment: Да, я это хотел сказать, что мне приходит сообщение, что ресурс не найден

Comment: Ну, значит ссылка ошибочная или не рабочая.

Comment: У меня с таблицами всё работает с этим же base_url. Вот, например, я создал таблицу, с которой всё отлично работает - `https://disk.yandex.ru/i/llgg_aCS4ryYCw` - проверьте её, останется ли у вас проблема.

Comment: Ещё внимательно проверьте ввашу ссылку - я смотрю в вашем примере кода написано `disk.yandex.ru/d/`, а у меня на большинство файлов, которую я расшариваю, создаётся ссылка с `disk.yandex.ru/i/`. Я не знаю, в чём именно разница между `/d/` и `/i/`, но писать ссылку очевидно нужно именно так, как её сгенерил сервис.

Comment: У меня та же самая таблица и та же самая ссылка работают сейчас. Мне кажется, что это может быть какой-то баг Яндекса или ещё чего. Но временами скачать таблицу я могу, а временами нет
Может это быть связано как-то с владельцем таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

С кодом всё в порядке. Файл, расположенный на диске превысил лимит загрузки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, объясните, как вы пришли к такому выводу.